# Ionic cordova platform add android giving error EPEERINVALID

Tags: ionic2

```
user@com10:/var/www/html/excalibur-mobile$ ionic cordova platform add android
> cordova platform add android --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@7.0.0

Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@7.0.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/var/www/html/excalibur-mobile/node_modules/.bin/npm" "install" "cordova-android@7.0.0" "--save"
npm ERR! node v9.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @ionic-native/core@3.12.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/app-rate@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/call-number@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/diagnostic@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/email-composer@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/geolocation@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/in-app-browser@4.3.1 wants @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/insomnia@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/keyboard@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/location-accuracy@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/network@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/onesignal@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/photo-viewer@4.7.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/shake@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/social-sharing@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/splash-screen@3.12.1 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/sqlite@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/status-bar@3.12.1 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/youtube-video-player@4.2.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 || >=4.0.0
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.3.1",
    "@ionic-native/insomnia": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/shake": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/youtube-video-player": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-email": "^1.2.6",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "es6-promise-plugin": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include your package.json please?

Comment: @SurajRao have shared package.json. Also for every plugin its now giving me same error

Comment: you need to update `ionic-native` packages. Ideally they should be at the `@ionic-native/core` version

Comment: @SurajRao thanks....updating core did the work!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem ,I uninstalled the cordova-sqlite-plugin plugin and installed it in the latest version (currently 2.2.0). That fixed this problem for me:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-sqlite-plugin
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-plugin@2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated ionic-native/core to the version of my rest of the native packages